# How to power off a hard drive to essentially "hot swap"

Tags: scripting, electrical-power, hard-drive, hotswap

I'm looking for either freeware or the programming basics to power off/on a hard drive.  Mounting and unmounting a hard drive is simple enough just using the command prompt in Windows XP.  Now I need to be able to power down the hard drive so it will not become damaged when being unplugged.  I would prefer this to be a simple doable in the command prompt, a simple script, or at worst C++/C#.  Freeware that does this exact requirement would also do the job.

This script/program will run on Windows XP with .NET 2.0 SP1.

Comment: If the machine isn't designed for hot-swapping then it may not be safe to hot-swap the drive.

Comment: First and foremost: this can only be done with hard-drive interfaces that support hot-swapping (like SATA). A "regular" PATA IDE hard-drive cannot and should not be hot-swapped - due to the way this hardware and related hardware (like the Motherboard's PATA IDE controller) initializes and works.

Answer (score 1):

M.A. Hanin is correct, once the drive is unmounted it's simply a case as to whether or not the drive, controller and power supply were designed to allow for removal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SATA 2 supports hot-swap natively. All you need is to buy a hot-swap kit. So a google search on "SATA 2 hot swap enclosure" will give you plenty of choice.